# Python in Terminal ( How to go to the second line in define Function )

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, terminal, user-defined-functions

I am new with Python, my problem is when I want to write second line in define function in Terminal (mac), then I press Enter but it runs instead of go to the second line with this symbol (...)

```
>>> def test():

... print "this a test"

File "<stdin>", line 2

 print "this a test"
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
>>>
```

which key I have to press ... !?
sorry I know it is really stupid question, but it is my problem.

Comment: Tab? Space bar? There should be tons of tutorials describing how to use command-line python.

Comment: "which key I have to press" - did you try using an English dictionary, in order to understand what the word "indentation" means?

Answer (score -1):

You need to press tab in the second line.

```
>>> def test():
...     print "this is a test"
...
>>>
```

Comment: or spaces (I use two spaces in python shell, 4 in code in files)